# getting following exception " io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.CucumberExpressionException"

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, automation-testing, selenium-java

## [ I have created one sample feature file for login functionality,

after running feature file i am getting following exception "java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.CucumberExpressionException"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWGpL.png)

I have created one sample feature file for login functionality,
after running feature file i am getting following exception

Comment: Please include the code of your step definitions in your question. Do not use screenshots.